# How to stop touch event if not left the finger

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch, user-interaction

I have a problem that, if i put a finger on a view, and I implement the `touch Began/Move/End/Cancel` functions.

Than I draw some other content on the view. But I want to make sure if the user still put his finger on the view(`touch Move`), I can somehow let it call (`touch Cancel/End`) by setting some property or call some function?

I have checked, but it's just `suspend`, the

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

and for the property of UIView `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO`, also not stop the `touch Move` if that finger is start before I change the property, and keep on the screen even after I change the property.

Actually I can add a local variable like `IsTouchShouldWork` to put into all the touch functions to detect if should I call may logic. But which is not so good. I just want a better way. like set some property or call some system apis.

Any idea?

**More Explains:**

- View A => render with content A; with a touch event implement A;
- Update:(Click a button A)
- View A => render with content B; with another touch event implement B;

View A is multi-touch enabled.

- Expect: when click button A. all the touch event implement A can call the touch-End/Cancel to end.
  than start event implement B;
- Actually: if I put one finger one view A. and keep it on the screen. than another finger click button A. the finger A still call the event implement A. not call the event implement B.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want stop touch event ?

Comment: @KudoCC  Because I have change the content of the view, but the touch event logic is different.  (The view is same view, I render the different content, so I give another touch event in another implement)

Comment: I find difficult to understand what you are asking in the question. Maybe having some code with some explanation of what you are trying to do..

Comment: @KudoCC and another situation is I will add a cover view like loading, which is translucency, and when that shows up i need to stop the touch event. and after that loading finish start over with touch events.

Comment: I think app should reflect the action user act, it is not good to interrupt the action.

Comment: @DanSpag check the More Explains pls

Comment: @KudoCC I agree that. in the situation i meet. actually the user will think that they change the view.(View A just changed the content).